# Pub package update management

Tags: android-studio, flutter, package

Am I the only one who thinks that the pub package manager is a good base but lack some basic stuff (compare to Nugget on VS)?

Installing a new package is very easy : just add a line of code in the pubspec.yaml file.

But how do you manage updates? If you do not specify a version you've got almost automatic update, and if you do, you just don't have any update at all. Is there any way you can have notification when a package update is available, and chose one by one if you update it or not, based on the changelog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin is exactly what I was looking for! 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12400-flutter-pub-version-checker

Combined with the sementic versionning explained by @Remi, it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

Dart packages use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/).

TL;DR about semver:

- major = breaking changes
- minor = new features
- patch = bug fixes.

Combined with version constraints you can have custom behavior.

For example, the following will accept only bug fixes for the `1.0.0` version of a package named `some_package`:

```
dependencies:
  some_package: ^1.0.0
```

Similarly, this constraint accepts all newer releases besides breaking changes:

```
dependencies:
  some_package: '>=1.2.3 <2.0.0'
```

See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#version-constraints for more information.

Comment: That's quite nice thanks !
Is there any way to have notifications of new releases ? 
Because using the second option seems very nice, but you'll never now when a major package update is available nor when a minor update is installed...
Moreover, how can I know which version is installed ?